# Change the colour of the dots in "i's"?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to create the text in the following image purely via css/html (or any other means)? Essentially any dots in any "i's" will need a different colour.

Ideally I want this to be input via a Wordpress WYSIWYG (as the client can input whatever they want) as a H2.

I would attempt something first but don't even know where to start!

[image]

Comment: I would recommend canvas element for drawing the letter or just use svg format to attain the effect with scalability.

Comment: I am afraid that it will be extremely hard to achieve, so i don't say impossible...because the Dot (technical name "title") of the letter "i" is attached to the letter itself while the type is designed and i find it impossible to separate them. i thought of creating a custom letter "i" using svg and read it as woff but i think we will find a difficulty if the user changes the font color through WYSIWYG.

Comment: To reduce your time here is a fiddle I tried before this was marked as duplicate: http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/gf0m86Le/1/

Answer (score 0):

I done it, but it's very hard to position it!

```css
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

.white {
    
}

#blue {
    top: 5px;
    color: blue;
    -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
    transform: scale(1, -1);
    z-index: 3;
}

#black {
    z-index: 1;
}

#white-blue {
    width: 200px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    top: 28px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#white-black {
    z-index: 4;
    width: 200px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="white-blue"></div>
<h2 class="logo" id="blue">re-imagine</h2>
<div id="white-black"></div>
<h2 class="logo" id="black">re-imagine</h2>
```

Comment: If your voted down, please comment your ideas

Comment: AleshaOleg// You maybe pissed off. I voted up!

Comment: @Deckard thanks for it, but somebody voted down, and haven't sad why, I hate this moment. Maybe I have wrong answer, but is that so hard to explain why?

Comment: Not the downvoter but the reason is simple. Your dot is not aligned and the answer is complex than the simple solution in duplicated question.

Comment: @ManojKumar but you dots too large:( Could you make it more smaller?

Comment: Done: http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/gf0m86Le/1/